# Twilio Sending via MMS with Messaging Service

Tags: twilio, postman

I tried this originally via PHP, but I'm just trying to simplify it and make sure I can get things to work in Postman first..

Here's the curl code from postman

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'Body=test message here' \
--data-urlencode 'To=+12015550050' \
--data-urlencode 'MessagingServiceSid=MGxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'mediaURL=https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg[![enter image description here][1]][1]'
```

And a screenshot
[image]

I'm getting the text but not the jpg.  And when I run a GET on the subresource_uris:media url I'm getting a 404 that the resource was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case for `mediaURL` is not correct. It should be `MediaUrl`.